# How to limit the number below the 1 in text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="numeric-input">
  <input type="text" value="1" min="1">
  <span class="arrow-up"><i class="icons icon-up-dir"></i></span>
  <span class="arrow-down"><i class="icons icon-down-dir"></i></span>
</div>
```

I try to limit this by placing the min value 1 bt it does not work.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input type="number`

```
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
```

Using this also doesn't need to create `up and down arrows` yourself to `increase` and `decrease` value.

Comment: Example here http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Answer (score 0):

You have use input type="text" change this like

```
 <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min="1" attr in your input field

Comment: He has already used `min="1"`, but `input` elements don't have the capability to control min and max values.

Comment: Then use javascript to restrict value

Comment: There is no harm in using `input type="number". It has in-built capabilities to handle min and max values. Why would someone need JS for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **type="number"**

```
<input type="number" value="1" min="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of input text field, you can give "maxlength" to it. maxlength limit the maximum number of text you can type inside of it.

`<input type="text" value="1" maxlength="1">`